# Find elem by full text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to get a tag by text, but I only need the full text.

For example

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'VAN')]").click()
```

I find both “VAN” and also “AVANZA”, I only need “VAN”. How to use regular expression in this case?

Edit:

There are elements on the page

```
<a href="javascript:{};">AVANZA</a>
<a href="javascript:{};">VAN</a>
```

and others, there are many. I need to get for example "VAN", but it finds "AVANZA" first

Edit:

I found the solution

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='VAN']").click()
```

This works great, we can close the issue.

Comment: i don't really understand what is happening here.. can you fully explain what the output looks like?

Comment: There are elements on the page

`<a href="javascript:{};">AVANZA</a>`
`<a href="javascript:{};">VAN</a>`

and others, there are many. I need to get for example "VAN", but it finds "AVANZA" first

Comment: Yes, if you use contains, it finds any element that contains the text, if you use equals, it finds the one with text equal to that. By the way, you can answer your own question, if you think it isn't a duplicate and will be useful to others in the future (instead of just editing your question to include the solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='VAN']").click()
```

This works great.